# Files being destroyed without consent

Tags: laptop, data-loss

My laptop's internal HDD was destroyed along with all its files, MY memories/work. I bought a new one. It appears not to have any issues, but I can't trust this. This has been very hard for me, but thank you everyone for your help, sincerely.

---

When I originally posted this, I had not seen any evidence of files being lost on my internal hdd, not since installing ubuntu 13.01. Unfortunately, I was wrong. I keep losing files. Years of my life, pictures of loved ones, art and music by myself and my friends. I'm losing it. It appears to be going after older files first, especially anything with "back up" in the title, nested folders, and almost exclusively destroys personal content. I believe the problem was lying dormant for the last couple months. suddenly it's popped up, and just when I was starting to believe that AT LEAST Ubuntu Linux had helped me saved most of my stuff. 
I received a new external hdd today. I'll try to save what i can.

original post:
My computer is an ASUS G7VW. While running Windows 7, my files started disappearing and being moved and even copied, without my consent. I did a full install of ubuntu 13.01 (it gave me the option to preserve my personal files, but otherwise fully format the drive. everything seemed fine and I was able to recover most of my files since Ubuntu read my HDD correctly and most of the problem had been in the directory. However, the problem continues to ravage my two external HDDs. I haven't found any evidence that it's messing up the contents of my `/home` folder, but files and folders on both my external HDDs continue to be "mislocated."

One of my external drives (toshiba desktop external drive) is fairly new; the other (seagate freeagent goflex) is a bit older. I'm certain that the age of the drive is not a factor in this context. Both external drives and the laptop hdd are 1TB drives. Neither of the external drives have been damaged physically, or even so much as left in a hot/freezing car. I did only find out a couple months ago that usb is not "hot-swappable" but now I always unmount then disconnect the drive. The problem has persisted since i've wised up.

The drive healthSMART util included in Ubuntu says all drives are healthy. Still, it takes an extremely long time to copy or burn data, from the Ubuntu drive or the USB  drives (if that helps). I've recently been trying `rkhunter, clamtk, and comodo to eliminate the possibility of a virus, so far it's turned up nothing significant. At least I'm learning a lot about Ubuntu Linux... but I hope someone can shed some light on what's messing with my personal files.

Update: I found out why Clamtk wouldn't scan the external drives; it has to run from the terminal via gksu clamtk to select that option. Frustratingly, it's reported well over 300 possible "threats" on either hdd, the vast majority of which are not viruses or malware, and since you have to go through them one by one. it's been very time consuming, but I'm hoping it will be worth the effort.

Update & more info: Both of the external drives use the NTFS file system, and the internal drive was formatted with the default filesystem used by ubuntu 13.01 (ext3?). the external toshiba drive is now reporting "Contents: 207,907 items, totalling 955.0 GB (some contents unreadable)" ... I don't know why any of it would be unreadable, and that sound about 200GB more than I thought it was holding, but that's just a guestimate.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "mislocated"?

Comment: i mean folders no longer contain what they should, and some files & folders have vanished entirely.

Comment: one folder contained 1-7 additional copies of nearly all the files inside it. my files are in one big increasingly confusing mess.

Comment: Though the possibility of a virus is remote, it can't be ruled out. Is it possible for you to scan the drive/partition using an antivirus software? You can have a look at some [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus).

Comment: Are you certain the disk itself is not going bad? It sounds to me like the disk is in fact simply going bad. Corrupted or disappearing files is one thing that may happen when the disk itself goes bad. It could also be the controller for the disk, while the disk itself is ok.

Comment: If it's an external USB drive, buy a new external USB disk enclosure, and move the disk from the old one to the new one. If it's the controller anyway. If it's the disk, you'll need a new disk.

Comment: it's actually happening to two different USB drives, so unless it's both controllers, that isn't the problem... i think. right?

Comment: if it is happening to both drives, then no, the problem is most likely not with the dives themselves. a virus could be to blame but if you switched to ubuntu then the virus would no longer be able to operate and the problem would go away. another possibility is that a virus (or another abnormal action) damaged both drives in an identical fashion. Barring those possibilities, the only thing i can think of is a faulty motherboard, or corrupt (or poorly made) bios... those issues would be fixed with a new motherboard or flashing the bios...

Comment: @konner i've never updated a bios before, but i'm willing to give it a try. however, it might be a problem that my laptop isn't supported by linux. it's an asusg75vm. all i could find were windows related instructions. any suggestions? (i'll keep looking)

Comment: updating the bios would typically be done with a utility provided by the manufacturer (usually for windows). beyond that i couldnt really give you anything useful. You might want to actually try contacting the manufacturer for information on the process... as for what laptops are supported, im not a ubuntu dev so i couldnt tell you much. both of those could stand to be posted as questions (perhaps the bios flashing would be best suited for another stack exchange forum)... dont do anything irreversible on my word alone, im no expert..

Comment: i will say this though... if there is data being irrecoverably deleted from your hdd without consent, i HIGHLY recommend discontinuing use of those drives until you know your PC isnt damaging them... pull them out and boot from a live usb or cd... try to get a new drive... but dont risk losing more data to a possibly faulty motherboard

Comment: i'm sorry i've never asked for help before, and only been using ubuntu for about a month. i have no idea what information is relevant and what is not. this is pretty confusing to me.

Comment: Relevant information will usually include the model of computer, the model of the hard drives in question, what steps you took to install/format them etc initially, the version of the operating system, what you have tried so far and the specific text of any error messages that appear when trying to do something that should work. Now, it's generally a good idea to include this sort of info with any question even if you're not sure it's relevant. In this case it seems like the problem is going to be a hard-to-diagnose-online one so don't be disheartened if people find it difficult to answer.

Comment: @neon_overload thank you. yes, it is a difficult problem. i've run it by a few friends who work in computers/networking. i'm about 300 pages into the apress "beginning ubuntu linux" book, and have been making every effort to resolve this on my own... but i need outside perspectives. again, thank you.

Comment: @b-girl if you are actively trying to solve the problem, i recommend editing your question, and including any new information you may have. i have ofered a bounty on the question hoping to get you some help from a more experienced user... (that means that the person who solves your problem will be awarded, in this case, 50 reputation points)

Comment: How do you transport the drives, at any time have they been dropped, left in the heat/cold, near magnets?

Comment: hm, what format are you using for the file system, are these drives shared with a windows computer/ dual boot(if so do you use hibernate on windows). and how do you remove the drive from ubuntu (i.e. eject, safely remove, from the file manager or the launcher)

Comment: @Mateo i updated the original question to include some answers to your questions, so everyone will start with that knowledge.

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen thank you for your help. i've ordered a new 2TB external hdd, so asap i'll boot from a live cd and salvage as much data as i can from the two external drives... i just hope this one doesn't also go belly-up. :)

Comment: i ran nautilus from terminal via gksu and the "some contents unreadable" vanished. still, i've never had a hdd give me that before under contents (in the drive properties window), so i don't know how/why it happened.

Comment: @b-girl if it does go bad, at least you'll know its the PC with the problem, not the HDD =)

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen i'm guessing that if it does screw up the new hdd, which will be formatted ext4 or ext3, i'll learn one thing. since the laptop's internal hdd has shown no signs of the problem since i installed linux, we'll have narrowed it down to a bios or other internal laptop memory issue (like RAM, video card, etc.)... Right?

Comment: Is your mouse working well? For drag & drop mainly? I saw something similar happening with a defective left-mouse button, the user was moving files while passing the mouse over the directory in nautilus... with a touchpad I guess it would be even worst.. Are system files being moved too?

Comment: @laurent the mouse is fine. this started when i was using windows on my previous laptop (and the external drive), then persisted when i got a new laptop (and an additional hdd), on which i continued to run windows 7. then, after i installed linux, the problem appears to have stopped on my laptop, but continues on both the external hard drives.
also, the problem couldn't be related to a drag & drop issue, because when i transferred my files onto the external drive it went fine, and i double checked. the files get "mislocated" the NEXT time i attempt to access that drive. so frustrating!

Comment: @b-girl this would indicate there is something wrong with the NTFS volume, have your tried running [chkdsk](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chkdsk.mspx?mfr=true) from Windows or [ntfsfix](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/ntfsfix.8.html) from linux? You also might want to run a full surface scan on your disk. I recomend [Seagate's SeaTools](http://origin-www.seagate.com/support/downloads/item/seatools-dos-master/)

Comment: @Symin thank you, i'll try that right now. however, this is a full install of ubuntu linux, there shouldn't be an NTFS volume.

Comment: @b-girl I think that, At least, you can recover your files with out it's file name due detect a magic of file content.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check the disk's health.  The two tools I would use are smartctl (if your H.D.D.s support S.M.A.R.T.) and e2fsck.  Those should check for hard drive issues and attempt to repair the filesystem if they can.

The two things that make me suspect hard drive damage: 1) Disappearing files 2) Slow transfer speeds.

If that's not it, you might want to look at auditd which should tell you who/what is moving your files (assuming they are being moved).  If you enable that and it shows you nothing, it's probably hard drive failure.

[auditd tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html)

[smartctl tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/checking-hard-disk-sanity-with-smartmontools-debian-ubuntu)

Comment: for a new user... details on how to use these tools (or at least links to the docs) would be invaluable...

Comment: i will check out those apps. it can't hurt, but i feel that since it was happening to three drives before installing ubuntu, and two drives since, drive damage is unlikely the cause. but thank you! auditd might help, except that according to the files themselves, they have not been moved/accessed/altered since originally saved to the external drive.

Comment: You can't trust the access times, you can alter those yourself very very easily.  Try 'touch -t 2010010100 fileName' and the timestamp on that file will be set to 01/01/2010 00:00.  Anyways, I re-read over your post, can you give us an idea of your disk setup?  Are all 3 disks separate, or are they in an LVM volume group?  What filesystem is on them?

Comment: @seth all 3 are separate. the internal is using the ubuntu linux default filesystem, and the external drives are using the default windows7 filesystem.
also, i have run the drive health SMART util included in ubuntu, and all drives are healthy.

Comment: Ah, I did not realize you were using NTFS on the external drives; I thought you had reformatted all of them.  New guess: Windows 7 corrupted the NTFS filesystem on those drives.  That would explain why the two externals don't work, but the internal now does work (because the NTFS filesystem has been formatted).  Look at [chkdsk](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/), which will require a Windows computer.  After you repair them, I would suggest switching to ext3/4 on those if you can.  Linux support for NTFS is not great.

Comment: @Seth my neighbor runs windows (and is a retired networking specialist), and said we can try chkdsk monday sometime, since it's easter. i'll get back to you with the results asap. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

so you probably get a virus on the computer,so install anti virus to Ubuntu(avg is good anti virus) and if you download avg write this command(the avg has not graffical user interface)
`sudo avgscan` and where do you want to scan(for example the place where you mount the filesystem where has the ubuntu) sorry for my bad English